# React: Pass state or data from parent to child component which is in object

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-props

I was trying to pass state or data as props from parent to a child which was in the **state object**. When a button is clicked on the parent component, the div of the child component will show the changes in true or false.

The child component successfully rendered the changes when <Child/> was placed directly in the parent, but it did not if the <Child/> was declared in object (state). I have tried the context i.e. createContext in the parent component and useContext in the child, it did not display successfully also.

How can the child component render the changes if it is in the state object in the parent component?

Please refer to the below example:

Parent.js (**Successful code**)

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import Child from './Child'

function Parent() {
    const [childs, setChilds] = useState()
    const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(true)
    const changeToggle = () => {
        setToggle(!toggle)
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        setChilds(<div><Child modeToggle={toggle} /></div>)
    }, [])

    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                <button onClick={changeToggle}>Change toggle</button>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div><Child modeToggle={toggle} /></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Parent
```

Parent.js (**unsuccessful code**)

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import Child from './Child'

function Parent() {
    const [childs, setChilds] = useState()
    const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(true)
    const changeToggle = () => {
        setToggle(!toggle)
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        setChilds(<div><Child modeToggle={toggle} /></div>)
    }, [])

    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                <button onClick={changeToggle}>Change toggle</button>
            </div>
            <div>
                {childs}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Parent
```

Child.js

```
import React, {  useEffect } from 'react'

function Child(props) {
    useEffect(()=>{
        console.log(props.modeToggle)
    },[props.modeToggle])

    return (
        <div>{props.modeToggle.toString()}</div>
    )
}

export default Child
```

The snapshot of the web browser:
[Web snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wiE3k.png)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `toggle` inside the effect hook is in a stale closure:

```
useEffect(() => {
    setChilds(<div><Child modeToggle={toggle} /></div>)
}, [])
```

The above callback only runs once, so the `childs` that exists will always have a `modeToggle` prop of the initial value of `toggle`, which is `true`. Even if `changeToggle` is called, since the `useEffect` callback doesn't run again, the `childs` remains with its initial `toggle` prop.

I'd conditionally render the `childs` instead - put a boolean into state indicating whether or not to render it, so the prop can be passed down naturally in the parent's returned JSX:

```
function Parent() {
    const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(true)
    const changeToggle = () => {
        setToggle(!toggle)
    }

    const [showChilds, setShowChilds] = useState(false);
    useEffect(() => {
        setShowChilds(true);
    }, [])

    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                <button onClick={changeToggle}>Change toggle</button>
            </div>
            <div>
                {
                  showChilds
                    ? <div><Child modeToggle={toggle} /></div>
                    : null
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@CertainPerformance, thanks for answering. I have based on your answer to getting a similar solution. Thank you very much.

It seems there is no way to directly get the updated value if it is in state object.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import Child from './Child'

function Parent() {
    const [childs, setChilds] = useState()
    const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(true)
    const changeToggle = () => {
        setToggle(!toggle)
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        setChilds(<div><Child modeToggle={toggle} /></div>)
    }, [toggle])

    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                <button onClick={changeToggle}>Change toggle</button>
            </div>
            <div>
                {childs}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Parent
```